# PHP Web Proxy configuration

Tags: php, web

Does anyone know how to setup php web proxy. This is adress of project http://sourceforge.net/p/php-proxy/support-requests/. I have configured config.php with server I want to acess, but when I use URLproxyServer I never get content.

Thanks
Zlaja

Comment: PHP Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/classWebPage.php on line 84
[Wed Aug 21 16:42:27 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.11] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: file in /var/www/URLproxyServer.php on line 128
[Wed Aug 21 16:42:27 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.11] PHP Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/URLproxyServer.php on line 83
[Wed Aug 21 16:42:27 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.11] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/URLproxyServer.php on line 69

Answer (score 0):

If you will access some content by hp using proxy, try use CURL:

```
    $url = 'URL';
    $proxy = 'PROXY URL';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_exec ($ch); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //$result 

    echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

Comment: I just want that users access server A which acts as proxy to server B. Users should never see server B.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you said. User will access page `A`, that page will send `proxy` request to the page `B` and page `A` will display result from page `B`. User will never know about page `B`.